# How do you add a simple counter column that increases by one in each row to a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been running into this problem a lot. If you have an existing DataFrame in Pandas, and you want to add a row that is simply an increasing count, ie. 0, 1, 2..., what is the most efficient way to do it?

Thanks!

Sam

Comment: Do you want to add a row or a column? (title and body of question contradict each other)

Answer (score 23):

The easiest way might be

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

This will give you a new index starting at 0.

You could also do

```
df['counter'] = range(len(df))
```

Comment: perhaps `np.arange(len(df))` may be more optimal?

Comment: You want to replace the current index instead of saving it as new column use `df.reset_index(drop=True)`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set a specific starting point that's not zero based, say 100:

```
   initial_value = 100

   df['Counter'] = range(initial_value, len(df) +initial_value)
```

For negative numbering just multiply initial value by -1:

```
   initial_value = 100 * -1

   df['Counter'] = range(initial_value, len(df) +initial_value)
```

I